# Menu Access Keys missing underline display in Chromium, Brave, Chrome

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, chromium, menu, brave

I'm using Kubuntu 2022.04.1 but it has happened for other versions of my Linux for a long time. Menu Access Keys are missing. The visual underline of accelerator access keys within menus for Brave / Chromium are missing. How do I restore these underlines?

**How to reproduce this problem:**

1. Use your mouse to right-click on an image.
2. The mouse menu will appear, showing command options.
3. There is no underlined letters within the option. It is missing the accelerator keys.
   Expected result: When displaying the mouse menu, the available commands should have at least a single letter underlined. For example, ‘Save Image’ should have the letter letter ‘v’ underlined.

[image]

Brave Version: v1.49.120 (Mar 9, 2023)

Additional Information: The keys can still be typed and will perform their action. For example, ‘Save Image’ still works with the letter ‘v’ on my system. It will trigger saving. However the display is no longer there. This is the same problem for the general Brave which can be accessed by the three flat lines button.